# background-image not working in chrome with New Update of Chrome Browser

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, image, google-chrome

With latest update of chrome background-image not showing in chrome browser .Where as working fine with Fire Fox and IE.Before Chrome update it worked well .

```css
.headersearchbutton {
    float: right;
    text-indent: -999em;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url(../images/internal-submit-sprite.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Tried with some google solutions but didn't worked .

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to include quotes around the image location.

Comment: Try with double/single quote. background-image: url("../images/internal-submit-sprite.gif");

Comment: Also clear your browser cache and check the developer tools for an error message.

Comment: Is this happening on a local development domain? You should check what's happening in the network tab of chrome's dev tools - it's possible that it's blocking a non-HTTPS request.

Comment: Hi @Zhaph - Ben Duguid - Not only in Local domain - with public domain also same issue .I will check with above solutions and will update comments

Comment: AndyG  and RanjitKumar no positive result with double/single quote

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357587/the-ssl-certificate-used-to-load-adsafeprotected-com-will-be-distrusted-in-m66 might help you

Comment: Hi Hina Khuman ,Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) it is not working . Where as it worked with 62 chrome version .Is there any solution to fix this ?